# Polular componente select na pagina html com dados vindos da tabela

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho uma variável php que possui seu valor.

ex: "AREA 05"

Esta é exibida no input. Tenho uma tabela que está relacionada os logins de acordo com estas áreas. 
Como faço e se é possível usar esta variável do php para popular a tag select do html com seus respectivos logins, ou seja o select ser populado de acordo com sua area. É possivel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas se deseja fazer algo dinâmico, assincrono, que quando a pessoa for selecionar o item no select, tu consiga fazer uma nova busca no banco e popular a tabela, tu pode usar [AJAX com PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) da uma olhada no exemplo na [W3SCHOOL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) se é isso que procura.

Comment: não é popular a tabela e sim popular o item select de acordo com o resultado da variável php.

Comment: Exatamente, tu pode usar o php ajax para conforme o usuário selecionar no select voce popular um outro select ou qualquer outro lugar, gerando consultas referente ao novo valor da variável, no caso tu estaria usando método get ou post da sua preferencia para passar o novo valor para a variável responsável pela consulta.

Comment: existe a possibilidade em me mostrar um exemplo??

Comment: Da uma lida nesse artigo no [DevMedia](https://www.devmedia.com.br/populando-selects-dinamicamente-com-ajax-json-e-php/27658) vai te ajudar com um exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Sim é possível, você vai ter que tratar com AJAX, quando for preenchido o campo input com **'AREA 05'**, Ira ser feita uma consulta via AJAX no banco com a referencia em **'logins'**, os resultados serão trazidos e exibido na listagem do **'select'**.

Se quiser, pode usar esse [exemplo](https://www.daviferreira.com/posts/populando-selects-de-cidades-e-estados-com-ajax-php-e-jquery/) para se basear.